# Save Feynman diagram files in a subfolder

Tags: external-files, metapost, metafont, folders, feynman

Suppose one has a simple Feynman diagram, such as the following MWE (which has to be run with `-shell-escape`, I guess this is to allow compilation to "escape the shell" to run metapost).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,braket,feynmp-auto}
\newenvironment{feynman}[1]{\begin{center}\begin{fmffile}{#1}\vspace*{\baselineskip}}{\vspace*{\baselineskip}\end{fmffile}\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{feynman}{01}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(110,65)
        \fmfleftn{i}{2}
        \fmfrightn{o}{1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,i2}
        \fmf{dashes,label=$\braket{\lambda_2|T|\lambda_1}$}{v1,o1}
        \fmfdotn{v}{1}
        \fmfv{decoration.shape=cross,decoration.filled=empty,decoration.size=0.1w}{o1}
        \fmflabel{$\lambda_2$}{i1}
        \fmflabel{$\lambda_1$}{i2}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{feynman}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the MWE.]

In the case of a large project, one wouldn't like to have all the `.1`, `.log`, `.mp` and `.t1` files to be in the main folder, but rather in a subfolder. When the name of the diagram is changed to for example `diagrams/01`, by changing the 5th line to

```
\begin{feynman}{diagrams/01}
```

only the file `01.mp` appears in the subfolder diagrams, the other files aren't created (it seems the second step in creating the diagram doesn't recognize the path), with as result no output in the pdf.

**Question:** How can we get whatever script/program that is being run to recognize the path to the `.mp` file? Or, more generally, how can we get the diagram files to be stored in a subfolder?

Comment: Unfortunately, `mpost` doesn't obey the `-output-directory` that's possible to use with other TeX programs. Complain with the maintainers.

Comment: @egreg Bug report/feature request has been filed at metapost@tug.org. Thanks for pinpointing the issue.

Comment: I thought about doing that for `feynmp-auto`, but making `mpost` run in a subdirectory would introduce heavy OS dependency. Possibly a solution is using `latexmk` with suitable rules.

Comment: You mean contacting the maintainers of `feynmp-auto` about the issue?
Pardon my stupidity, but how exactly would `latexmk` come into play here?

Comment: I'm the maintainer of `feynmp-auto`, so you have already contacted me. ;-) And I told you this feature can't be provided without `mpost` obeying the `-output-directory` command line option. Such a change can only be done by the maintainers of Metapost. Since `latexmk` can do postprocessing in a fairly general way, I believe it would be possible to adapt it to the task.